# Why is my function being returned correctly when prototyped outside of my constructor, but not when it's being used as a method within my constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a function constructor which needs to have a method being used as one of the properties within the constructor.  Normally, I'd simply create the function as a property like so:

```
var currentDate = new formatDate(new Date());
console.log(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.dayOfMonth, currentDate.dayOfWeek, currentDate.second);


function formatDate(dateHolder){
    this.monthsArray = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    this.daysOfWeekArray = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    this.date = new Date(dateHolder);
    this.year = this.date.getFullYear();
    this.month = this.monthsArray[this.date.getMonth()];
    this.dayOfMonth = this.addZero(this.date.getDate());
    this.dayOfWeek = this.daysOfWeekArray[this.date.getDay()];
    this.minute = this.addZero(this.date.getMinutes());
    this.second = this.addZero(this.date.getSeconds());
    this.addZero = function(i){
        if(i < 10){
            i = "0" +i;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

I've always been taught that this would work and is the way to do this.  However, whenever I run my application, I get the the error saying that `this.addZero` is not a function.  When I do the same thing, but prototype the `addZero` method like so

```
formatDate.prototype.addZero = function(i){
    if(i < 10){
        i = "0" +i;
    }
    return i;
}

function formatDate(dateHolder){
    this.monthsArray = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    this.daysOfWeekArray = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    this.date = new Date(dateHolder);
    this.year = this.date.getFullYear();
    this.month = this.monthsArray[this.date.getMonth()];
    this.dayOfMonth = this.addZero(this.date.getDate());
    this.dayOfWeek = this.daysOfWeekArray[this.date.getDay()];
    this.minute = this.addZero(this.date.getMinutes());
    this.second = this.addZero(this.date.getSeconds());
}
```

it works the way it's supposed to.

Can anyone explain to me why it's working one way but not the other, if I'm doing something wrong(and how to fix it), and which way is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `addZero` before you've defined it. Switch it around so that you define it first and it will work:

```
this.addZero = function(i){
    if(i < 10){
        i = "0" +i;
    }
    return i;
};
this.dayOfMonth = this.addZero(this.date.getDate());
this.dayOfWeek = this.daysOfWeekArray[this.date.getDay()];
this.minute = this.addZero(this.date.getMinutes());
this.second = this.addZero(this.date.getSeconds());
```

or, since the function doesn't use `this` you can just use a function declaration and rely on hoisting:

```
this.dayOfMonth = addZero(this.date.getDate());
this.dayOfWeek = this.daysOfWeekArray[this.date.getDay()];
this.minute = addZero(this.date.getMinutes());
this.second = addZero(this.date.getSeconds());

function addZero(i){
    if(i < 10){
        i = "0" +i;
    }
    return i;
};
```

Arguably you should always use the prototype whenever you can anyway (when the body of the function doesn't need access to any variables that are declared in the constructor). Functions added to the prototype are reused by every object, but functions created in the constructor are duplicated  (a new function is created for each object, which is not necessary when you don't use any variables that closed over).

Comment: So using the prototyped version is the better way to go?

Comment: @Robert Yes, for that function it is.

Comment: Would there be any benefit or disadvantage to hoisting?

Comment: Either use the prototype or declare it as a property of the constructor `EG.
 formatDate.addZero = function (i){ ...` and then use `formatDate.addZero( arg );` to call it.

Comment: @Robert Using the hoisted version has the same problem as declaring a function on each instance: Each object will have its own addZero, instead of sharing one function for every object.